# How do I access an inherited class's inner class and modify it?

Tags: python, django

So I have a class, specifically, this:

```
class ProductVariantForm_PRE(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductVariant
        exclude = ("productowner","status")
    def clean_meta(self):

        if len(self.cleaned_data['meta']) == 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'You have to select at least 1 meta attribute.'))

        for m in self.cleaned_data['meta']:
            for n in self.cleaned_data['meta']:
                if m != n:
                    if m.name == n.name:
                        raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'You can only select 1 meta data of each type. IE: You cannot select 2 COLOR DATA (Red and Blue). You can however select 2 different data such as Shape and Size.'))
        return self.cleaned_data['meta']
```

I wish to extend this class (a ModelForm), and so I have a class B.

Class B will look like this:

```
class B(ProductVariantForm_PRE):
```

How can I access the inner class "Meta" in class B and modify the exclude field?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for factory_boy `DjangoModelFactory` - I get `AttributeError: type object 'FooFactory' has no attribute 'Meta'`. I have had to fully redefine Meta without inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Django documentation for model inheritance [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance).  From that page:

> When an abstract base class is
>   created, Django makes any Meta inner
>   class you declared in the base class
>   available as an attribute. If a child
>   class does not declare its own Meta
>   class, it will inherit the parent's
>   Meta. If the child wants to extend the
>   parent's Meta class, it can subclass
>   it. For example:

```
class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['name']

class Student(CommonInfo):
    ...
    class Meta(CommonInfo.Meta):
        db_table = 'student_info'
```

Comment: I just realized you're talking about a Django Form class.  I'm not sure if my answer applies.